# Explain Can't Assign To Function Call Error

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

```
def func(lst):
    return lst[0]
 
 lst = [1,2,3]

 func(lst) = 5 #a

 lst[0] = 5 #b
```

Why does 'a' give me a "can't assign to function call" error and 'b' runs perfectly fine, even though they are saying the same thing. Please explain and/or provide alternatives to what I am trying to do. (Ignore faulty indentation)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: the function returns a list index. I want to change the value of that index when the returns. Id also like an explanation of why 'a' is wrong

Comment: your function is returning the value of an element in your list. 
`lst[0]` is the element indexes `0` which is 1.

Comment: So what exactly is your end goal?

Comment: you have to read up on C++ lvalue, and lvalue is anything that can be assigned, anything that has a memory location that will last longer than the statement, the function returns a temporary value that holds a constant, if it would return `lst` you could do `func(lst)[0] = 5`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `lst[0]=5` you are actually changing the first element of your list `lst` to 5. Therefore, you can `assign` the value 5.

However, when you do `func(lst)` for the algorithm, you are trying to give `func(lst)` a value 5, which is not doable.

However, what you can do is to check if `func(lst) == 5` Which means, does the value given by `func(lst) equal to 5 ?`

Answer (score 0):

What do you think it "should" mean, if you were allowed to do `func(lst) = 5`?

You seem to be fixated by the fact that, in this case, `func(lst)` happens to always equal `lst[0]`, and that you know this - but what would it mean if `func(lst)` where to, say, always return `2`? Would you expect that to mean you could set `2` equal to `5` (or whatever else you assigned)? That's clearly nonsensical. And what if the function didn't return anything?

The only things you can assign to are variables, and to object properties (of which list indices are a special case). A function call returns neither of these, but a *value*. Variables and object properties *hold* (or *contain*) a value, but they are not in themselves values. It makes sense to assign to one of these, but you can't assign to a value.

In particular the `lst[0]` that your function returns doesn't actually bear any relation to `lst` itself. That's just how your function calculates its value - it looks at the list its been passed and takes the first element. But once it has done that and found, say, 1 (as in your example), that value of 1 is just 1 - it is "detached" from the list.